# Fault exception on adding a new item to DataContract List<T>

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

I have a proxy wcf-service using data contracts from another wcf-service, which purpose is to amend or append objects.

In certain cases, i notice some bugs that agreements give exceptions when called through the proxy, but not directly on the direct wcf-service.

Looking into the problem, I noticed some (for me) strange behavior on collection changes:

When I clean the collection or remove items from the collection, it still gives back the result correctly. As soon as I try to add to the collection, it gives back a FaultException after serialization:

```
<s:Fault>
     <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
     <faultstring xml:lang="nl-NL">Message is closed.</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
           <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
           <Message>Message is closed.</Message>
           <StackTrace>at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.get_Properties()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CorrelationCallbackMessageProperty.TryGet(Message message, CorrelationCallbackMessageProperty&amp; property)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.FinalizeCorrelation(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
           <Type>System.ObjectDisposedException</Type>
        </ExceptionDetail>
     </detail>
  </s:Fault>
```

Example:

```
[DataContract]
public class AgreementDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<AgreementDto> Children;
```

When i call agreement.Children.Clean(), it works, but when i try agreement.Children.Add(new AgreementDto()) it only works in debug until it serializes.

Same (of course) when I create and call the ServiceClient in code.

Code

```
 public class AgreementService : BaseWcfServices
    {
          private readonly IProxyFactory<IAgreementsService> agreementsServiceProxyFactory;

           public AgreementService(IProxyFactory<IAgreementsService> agreementsServiceProxyFactory)

         {
            this.agreementsServiceProxyFactory= agreementsServiceProxyFactory
         }

        public AgreementDto GetAgreement(string agreementReference)
        {
                var agreement = agreementsServiceProxyFactory.Create().GetAgreement(agreementReference);

                agreement.Children.Add(new AgreementDto());

                return agreement
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Apparently ApplicationInsight swallows the REAL exception and rethrows it's own one. In this case very confusing, but solved when using the SDK locally.